# put a background image after text

Tags: css

I have a header element into which I want to put a background image but I want to put it on end. So whatever the width of text is it will remain always after the text ending. Possible? How?

```
<h1>Here is my dynamic text</h1>
```

Comment: Can't you put a span and img into it ?

Comment: Try like: header{background: url('your-image-path');

Comment: I can put, but what would be the css to show it after the text

Comment: well, basicly nothing. Span and img are inline elements

Comment: you want to overlap the text above / below the background image? or share any sample ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to put it really *behind* the text you should use pseudoelements:

```
h1:after { content:url(myimage.png); }
```

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/XMFrP/).

If you want to have a *real* background image you can only do this if you change the `h1` to `display:inline`, since otherwise the element will stretch to the full width of its parent, thus losing all reference to the size of the contained text.

All other solutions (including the other ones mentioned here) require changing the HTML markup, and are as such not pure CSS solutions.

Comment: I think only this guy got this question, +1

Comment: Is this compatible on all browsers? got a feeling older versions of IE don't support this?

Comment: [IE8+](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent). Use the single-colon syntax, it's supported by all browsers (with double colon it's IE9+). [IE7- are more or less dead thankfully](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/06/01/ie10-blows-past-ie7-and-ie6s-combined-market-share-firefox-gains-too-but-chrome-hits-21-month-low/) and you shouldn't go patching stuff for them anymore in new sites.

Comment: Not sure I agree that IE7 *is more or less dead*. Depends on your target audience I suppose as market share fluctuates depending on which country is accessing you, etc. also the stats on market share are shaky at best.

Comment: @Liam do you have any sources that support your claim? IE7 is old as dirt and should be treated that way imo :)

Comment: @xec My Google analytics that says we still get enough traffic from IE7- for us to loose money if we didn't support it :P Look I'm **not arguing**, just making the point that it depends on your target. For me, I'll still try and support older browsers until people stop using them

Comment: Well it's fine with me if you want to support dead and buried browsers for your site (for commercial sites it's certainly not always dumb or stupid), but unless someone specifically adds to their question that they want to support 8-year old browsers I'm not going to consider them in my answers.

Comment: Also, there's a difference between 'supporting' and 'providing an identical experience'. I do check most of my sites in IE7-mode still today, but just to check whether it's still **usable**. Pixel-perfect identical is just not doable anymore with the cool stuff we do with cool browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```css
h1
{
background-image:url(https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/c6a0ac3e18f1cd8d0f1be4c2e3a4cfbd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right;
padding-right:40px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Here is my dynamic text</h1>
```

So backgorund image to the right with padding so it's always outside your text. The `display:inline-block` is important because it stops your test filling the whole line

Answer (score 3):

Simply at a span for that background image as a child of `<h1>`, like this:

```
<h1>Here is my dynamic text <span class="chevron"></span></h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
   position: relative;
}

.chevron {
   background: url(images/chevron.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
   width: xxpx;   /* width and height of image */
   height: xxpx;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: xxpx;  /* adjust the position of the image to the heading text from the top */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use :after in your css like

```
h1:after
{
   background:url(image path)no-repeat;/* apply your image here */
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    width:999em;
    height:25px;
    margin:10px 0 0 5px;
}
```

look for example http://jsbin.com/uzorew/1

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding div with background img

```
<h1>Here is my dynamic text <div id="dynamicimage"></div></h1>

#dynamicimage{
  background-image: url("images/myimg.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may i sure tyr this css :

```
h1 {
    height:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
h1:after {
    background:red;/* apply your image here */
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    width:999em;
    height:25px;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
}
```

your html :

```
   <h1>Here is my dynamic text </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) background image

Although several answers have already suggested the use of CSS's `:after`, none (at the time of my posting) have shown how to handle the sizing of the image.

Below you'll see that [the standard syntax for setting a background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background) can be applied to an empty `content` when (as shown in a few other answers) the [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example) is set to `absolute`.

The `width` and `height` properties will set the dimensions of the `after` pseudo element, but the image size needs to be set via the `background` shorthand or `background-size` properties.

*i.e.* to set the image size to match the size of the `after` element, use:

```
background: url( path to image ) no-repeat center/contain;
```

where `center/contain` will center and contain the image ;-)

Note that in the snippet below, where the image size **hasn't** been set correctly, the results are obviously incorrect:

```css
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
     /* no size or position settings */
    background: url(https://lorempixel.com/200/200/) no-repeat;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<h1>Here is my dynamic text</h1>
```

But in the following snippet, where the image size **has** been correctly set, the results are full of awesome:

```css
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
     /* size and position set properly */
    background: url(https://lorempixel.com/200/200/) no-repeat center/contain;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<h1>Here is my dynamic text</h1>
```

To adjust the size of the `after` pseudo element itself, change the `width` and `height` properties like so:

```css
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
     /* size and position set properly */
    background: url(https://lorempixel.com/200/200/) no-repeat center/contain;
     /* width and height of container reduced */
    width: .5em;
    height: .5em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<h1>Here is my dynamic text</h1>
```

And as pointed out by [Tepken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799478/tepken-vannkorn) in his answer, use the `top` property to adjust the vertical alignment. However, make sure the `after`'s parent also has its `position` property set, or the image will consider the `top` to be relative to one of its grandparents:

```css
h1 {
     /* the parent must have its position set also */
    position: relative;
}
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
     /* size and position set properly */
    background: url(https://lorempixel.com/200/200/) no-repeat center/contain;
     /* width and height of container reduced */
    width: .5em;
    height: .5em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    content: "";
     /* vertically align the image */
    top: .35em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Here is my dynamic text</h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

Very simple
    `<div class="content"><h1>Header<img src="one.jpg"></h1></div>`

include the image within the header

Comment: The solution here is fine, but the question is only tagged as CSS so I reckon OP was looking for a CSS only solution